# How to set initial value for input Vue component using v-model

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component:

```js
Vue.component('email-input', {
  template: '#tmpl-email-input',
  name: 'email-input',
  delimiters: ['((', '))'],

  props: ['name', 'required', 'value'],

  data: () => ({
    suggestedEmail: '',
    email: '',
  }),

  methods: {
    onInput() {
      this.checkEmail();
      this.$emit('input', this.email);
    },

    checkEmail() {
      Mailcheck.run({
        email: this.email,

        suggested: suggestion => {
          this.suggestedEmail = suggestion.full;
        },

        empty: () => {
          this.suggestedEmail = '';
        },
      });
    },

    confirmSuggestion(confirm) {
      if (confirm) this.email = this.suggestedEmail;
      this.suggestedEmail = '';
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.checkEmail = _.debounce(this.checkEmail.bind(this), 1000);
  },
});
```

using this template

```html
<template id="tmpl-email-input">
  <div>
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      :name="name || 'email'"
      :required="required"
      v-on:input="onInput"
      v-model="email"
    />
    <small class="email-correction-suggestion" v-if="suggestedEmail">
      Did you mean ((suggestedEmail))?
      <a href="#" class="btn-sm yes" @click.prevent="confirmSuggestion(true)">Yes</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-sm no" @click.prevent="confirmSuggestion(false)">No</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- Lodash from GitHub, using rawgit.com -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.4/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!-- Mailcheck: https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck -->
<script src="/js/lib/mailcheck.js"></script>

<script src="/js/views/partials/email_input.js"></script>
```

And I'm calling it using

```
<email-input name="email" required></email-input>
```

I'd like to set an initial value for this email input, something like

```
<email-input name="email" required value="test@test.com"></email-input>
```

and have that show in the input.

I assumed I could do this by simply setting email to this.value in data but that doesn't help. How can I do this?

Comment: add `:` before value. `:value="test@test.com"`

Comment: thank you for the comment. If I add : before value the template no longer compiles. So <email-input name="email" required="" :value="test@test.com"></email-input> causes the template to throw invalid expression: :value="test@test.com"

Comment: `:` is used to pass data to `props`. Not sure why error happens. Btw, you can not specify `name="email" required` becouse `email-input` is not an input but vue anchor.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `value` `prop` but you are not using it at all! So it doesn't really matter which value you pass down as `value` `prop`: it won't be used.

I think what you are trying to achieve is expose an API similar to the one exposed by `input` component. That can be done and it's [detailed in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

What Vue does to handle the `v-model` bindings is assuming the component will emit an `input` event passing the new value as `$event`. It will also pass down to the component a value to the `value` `prop`. So this 2-way binding is automatically handled by Vue as long as you define a `value` `prop` and emit an `input` event.

The problem is that your component acts as a middleware for the underlying `input` component but it is passing down a different binding instead of forwarding it.

Translating this into your component, you should not use `v-model` to pass down `email` to the `input` component but a combination of `:value` and `@input` bindings: you pass down the `value` `prop` of `email-input` component to the `value` `prop` of the `input` component and as handler of `input` event of the `input` component you should just emit another `input` event with the same `$event` payload.

Template:

```js
<template id="tmpl-email-input">
  <div>
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      :name="name || 'email'"
      :required="required"
      :value="value"
      @input="onInput($event.target.value)"
    />
    <small class="email-correction-suggestion" v-if="suggestedEmail">
      Did you mean ((suggestedEmail))?
      <a href="#" class="btn-sm yes" @click.prevent="confirmSuggestion(true)">Yes</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-sm no" @click.prevent="confirmSuggestion(false)">No</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- Lodash from GitHub, using rawgit.com -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.4/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!-- Mailcheck: https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck -->
<script src="/js/lib/mailcheck.js"></script>

<script src="/js/views/partials/email_input.js"></script>
```

> Note the change from `@input="onInput"` to `@input="onInput($event.target.value)"` so we have access to the new value in `onInput` method.

Component:

```js
Vue.component('email-input', {
  template: '#tmpl-email-input',
  name: 'email-input',
  delimiters: ['((', '))'],

  props: ['name', 'required', 'value'],

  data: () => ({
    suggestedEmail: ''
  }),

  methods: {
    onInput(newValue) {
      this.$emit('input', newValue);
      this.checkEmail();
    },

    checkEmail() {
      Mailcheck.run({
        email: this.value,

        suggested: suggestion => {
          this.suggestedEmail = suggestion.full;
        },

        empty: () => {
          this.suggestedEmail = '';
        },
      });
    },

    confirmSuggestion(confirm) {
      if (confirm) this.$emit('input', this.suggestedEmail);
      this.suggestedEmail = '';
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.checkEmail = _.debounce(this.checkEmail.bind(this), 1000);
  },
});
```

Note the change in `onInput` method: now it takes a parameter with the new value and emits an `input` event with that value **before** checking the email address. It's emitted in that order to ensure we have synced the value of the `value` binding before checking the address.

Also note the change in `confirmSuggestion` method: instead of updating `email` `data` attribute it just emits an `input` event.

That's the key to solve this issue: the old implementation forced us to have 2 different variables: one where parent component could pass down a value and another one `email-input` could modify to store the chosen suggestion.

If we just emit the chosen suggestion as a regular change then we can get rid of the `email` variable and work with just one binding.

---

*Suggestion totally not related with the issue:* you can use debounce directly in `methods` instead of replacing the method on `mounted` hook:

```js
Vue.component('email-input', {
      template: '#tmpl-email-input',
      name: 'email-input',
      delimiters: ['((', '))'],

      props: ['name', 'required', 'value'],

      data: () => ({
        suggestedEmail: ''
      }),

      methods: {
        onInput(newValue) {
          this.$emit('input', newValue);
          this.checkEmail();
        },

        checkEmail: _.debounce(function () {
          Mailcheck.run({
            email: this.value,

            suggested: suggestion => {
              this.suggestedEmail = suggestion.full;
            },

            empty: () => {
              this.suggestedEmail = '';
            },
          });
        }, 1000),

        confirmSuggestion(confirm) {
          if (confirm) this.$emit('input', this.suggestedEmail);
          this.suggestedEmail = '';
        },
      }
    });
```

Lodash will take care of binding `this` of the underlying function to the same `this` that called the debounced function.

Comment: Although Lodash documentation does not explicitly says anything about `this` context of the underlying function, that can be checked in the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L10304).